# Is there some kind of load event for web-workers?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I faced some problem when tried to use broadcast channel to communicate between main script and workers. I have code below in main script:

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('my_bus');
const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
const secondWorker = new Worker('second-worker.js');

channel.postMessage('1000');
```

and the similar code in both workers:

```
const bc = new BroadcastChannel('my_bus');

bc.onmessage = () => {
  console.log('worker get length');
}
```

The problem is when the message emitted from main script, workers are not loaded yet, so they skip the message. I am sure about it, because if I do something like this, it works fine:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  channel.postMessage('1000');
}, 100)
```

Is there some way to trigger callback after worker script has been loaded?

Comment: You can make the worker emit a message when they're loaded, and you listen to that message on main script.  That usually what we do with web workers. They emit a message to the main thread to say "I'm ready to receive stuff".

Comment: Wow, that is nice idea! Thank you!

Comment: @ZER0 That sounds like an answer, want to post it? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per last comment, I'll wrote my suggestion as answer:

You can make the worker emit a message when they're loaded, and you listen to that message on main script.
That usually what we do with web workers: they emit a message to the main thread to say "I'm ready to receive stuff".

A possible implementation could be:

```
// assumes the first `message` from workers is always the "loaded" ones
const loaded = w =>
  new Promise(r => w.addEventListener("message", r, { once: true }));

// Code runs inside async function, so we can use `await`
async function main() {
  const channel = new BroadcastChannel("my_bus");
  const worker = new Worker("worker.js");
  const secondWorker = new Worker("second-worker.js");

  await Promise.all([
    loaded(worker), 
    loaded(secondWorker)
  ]);

  // this will be post only once all the workers have been loaded
  channel.postMessage("1000");
}

// call the main function
main();
```

The workers' code will looks like:

```
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("my_bus");

bc.onmessage = () => {
  console.log("worker get length");
};

postMessage("loaded");
```